# R: Create group id in sparklyr dataframe with varying levels of aggregation

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, grouping, sparklyr

I have a sparklyr dataframe similar to the one generated with the code below.

```
# Load libraries
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

# Connect to spark
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")

# Creating example data
df <- read.table(text = "firm sector chapter
A         x     11
B         x     12
C         y     21
D         x     11
E         z     31
F         y     22
G         z     32", header=TRUE)

# Copying data to spark instance
sdf <- copy_to(sc,df, name = "sdf", overwrite=TRUE)
```

I want to create a `group_id` by sector such that:

1. firms in sector `y` each belong to their own group, and
2. firms in other sectors are grouped into a single id,

resulting in the following table

```
# Source: spark<sdf2> [?? x 4]
  firm  sector chapter group
  <chr> <chr>    <int> <int>
1 A     x           11     1
2 B     x           12     1
3 C     y           21     2
4 D     x           11     1
5 E     z           31     4
6 F     y           22     3
7 G     z           32     4
```

But so far, I'm struggling even with creating a `group_id` at the sector level. I have tried:

- `sdf %>% mutate(group_id = group_indices(sector))`
- `sdf %>% group_by(sector) %>% mutate(group_id = cur_group_id())`
- `sdf %>% group_by(sector) %>% mutate(group_id = seq_along(sector))`

But I get error messages. How can I achieve this in SparklyR?

Comment: Seems like `sector` is already a "group_id", just not with that name. What are you trying to do?

Comment: good point @IRTFM, that's just me creating a poor example. I'll modify it to make it more representative of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the old days the way to make a numeric group id was to convert a factor to numeric so this should still work (without any `group_by(.)` ) but factors are not a Spark data type so perhaps not correct, unless the operation sdf$(...) returns a character vector to R for processing.

```
#  sdf$group_id <- as.numeric( factor(sdf$sector) )
```

This has been requested in the past at least in the tidyverse word and this thread (https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/1185) suggests this might work:

```
 df$group_id <- sdf %>% group_by(sector) %>% group_indices
```

Neither of these is tested. I started to install Spark but the directions seemed incomplete. They did imply that I needed to install Hadoop which had similarly incomplete installation docs. So you audience might be limited.

Comment: installing R's `sparklyr` installs spark automatically, so you don't have to install Spark or Hadoop manually.  Simply do `install.packages("sparklyr")` and the example above should run smoothly.

Comment: thanks! I tried modified versions of your suggestions. 1) `sdf %>% mutate(group_id=as.numeric(factor(sector)))` gives a `Undefined function: 'factor'` error. 2)`sdf %>% group_by(sector) %>% group_indices` gives a `Error in UseMethod("group_indices") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_indices' applied to an object of class "c('tbl_spark', 'tbl_sql', 'tbl_lazy', 'tbl')"` error.

Comment: Odd, at least the second error. The `group_indices` function ought to be able to accept an object with those last 3 classes.